# How to define type record in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, oracle, database-migration, plpgsql, pg

I have this declaration of type is record in ORACLE .

```
TYPE t_column IS RECORD (
        COLUMN_NAME         user_tab_columns.COLUMN_NAME%type,
        COLUMN_EXPRESSION   user_ind_expressions.COLUMN_EXPRESSION%type,
        COLUMN_ID           user_tab_columns.COLUMN_ID%type,
        DATA_TYPE           user_tab_columns.DATA_TYPE%type,
        CHAR_LENGTH         user_tab_columns.CHAR_LENGTH%type,
        CHAR_USED           user_tab_columns.CHAR_USED%type,
        DATA_PRECISION      user_tab_columns.DATA_PRECISION%type,
        DATA_SCALE          user_tab_columns.DATA_SCALE%type,
        NULLABLE            user_tab_columns.NULLABLE%type,
        DESCEND             user_ind_columns.DESCEND%type
    );
```

Can you tell me please how can i define it in postgre so i can use it later in variable like :

```
procedure assertTableSignature(inTableName IN VARCHAR2, inColumns IN VARCHAR2, inTableSpace in varchar2, inAdditionalClause in clob := NULL, inRaise in boolean := TRUE) IS

    recColumn t_column;

begin
.
.
.
```

Comment: Have you looked at [Row type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-ROWTYPES) and [Record type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-RECORDS)?

Comment: For every table (or view) in the database, a type with the same name exists. So if you have a PL/pgSQL procedure that needs a record representing a row from an existing table, just declare a variable with the table's name as the type. e.g. `declare l_record some_table_name;`